# slam gmapping real time on rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, rviz, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am doing slam gmapping on my robot. i run rviz so that I can visualise the map real time. However, the map seems to take a long time before appearing.

rostopic echo /scan provides data quickly.
rostopic echo /map_metadata about 40seconds before data is being churned.
rostopic echo /map  gives a huge array of -1

since map_metadata has a delay 40 seconds, i am guessing this is the cause for the delay in the visualisation of map in rviz. Is there a parameter where i can tune to fasten map output?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225048/slam-gmapping-real-time-on-rviz/) by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) (maybe you want to have a look at wiki pages before asking questions about parameters) and the parameter `map_update_interval` which is by default set to 5.0.

Note that the visualization(!) of the map is actually not when scans are integrated, but only when a new gridmap is assembled and sent out over the topic. Also note, that the robot needs to move for scans to be integrated.

---

**EDIT**

Well, if the maps are distorted and it still takes a long time, you probably have some problem with the mapping process itself. Maybe also not enough processing power?
Parameters that might lower computational requirements: `throttle_scans`, `maxUrange`, `linear/angularUpdate`, `temporalUpdate`, `particles`.

However, note that some of those parameters might result in even worse maps.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [learner88](https://answers.ros.org/users/25005/learner88/) on 2016-01-31**:
Hi mig, thank you for your answers. I know of the parameter map_update_interval and have already lowered it to 1.0. But the processing still takes a long time and the subsequent maps produced are always distorted. Hence i thought that there may be some other parameters that I can tweak.